# Autowired repository is null in my @SpringBootTest class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, java-11, spring-test

I'm trying to test my GET end-point. To do that I need to load some data inside my in memory H2 database. I have the following test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserApiControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseRepository myRepository;

    ...

    @Before
    public void initializeDatabase() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the `initializeDatabase()` method I created several objects and use the repository method `.saveAndFlush()` to save them inside my database.

When I try to run this test class I have the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "....MyRepository.saveAndFlush(Object)" because "this.myRepository" is
> null

I saw some posts with the same errors but without a correct answer. I tried also to put the `@DataJpaTest` but nothing happend.
I also tried to add the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation but another error has appeared:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple
> declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class
> [com.egym.recruiting.codingtask.api.RankingApiControllerIntegrationTest]:
> [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper),
> @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
>
> ...

**UPDATE**

This is my Application.java class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "...", "....api",
        "....config" })
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);
    }

    ...
}
```

Inside my configuration directory I have:

- An OpenAPIDOcumentationConfig class where I enable swagger2
- A HomeController class use to redirect to OpenAPI api documentation

I don't think these one have an impact on my error.

Comment: Can you post your main spring class ... its annotations and configuration will affect the spring test setup as well.

Comment: I will update as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

We can create an myrepository bean instance in the test class to have the dependency wired.

We can try libraries like mockito to mock the beans in our test cases.

Comment: Could you be more specific or provide some code/documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Spring anotation @SpringBootTest will scan only beans that were declared under your file directory (and in subdirectories). In order to scan additional beans you need to provide directories with @ComponentScan annotation same way as you did in your SpringBootApplication class

Add test config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "...", "....api",
    "....config" })
public class TestConfig {
}
```

Link test config file to your test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
                classes= TestConfig.class)
public class UserApiControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseRepository myRepository;

    ...

    @Before
    public void initializeDatabase() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi krzysztof K, thank you for your answer. I Created a new class `TestConfig` equal to your (of course I replaced the `...` that I hid. Moreover I added the classes parameter in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. But nothing change. However I confirm that my test class is in a test direcotry that doesn't contain beans.